# "error":true,"message":"required parameters are not available" while checking api call using postman

Tags: php, mysql

i am learning how to connect android app with php admin panel with volley and for this i used a tutorial from [Javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-volley-library-registration-login-logout) , but i made two files as they told me to create and checked apicall in [Postman web](https://web.postman.co/), i got this error:

> "error":true,"message":"required parameters are not available"

i attached screenshot too [image: postman screenshot]

here is the structure of the tables where i want to get data from.

[image: screenshot5]

can anyone help me about this error, i really don't know how to solve it.

```
<?php   
  require_once 'connection.php';  
  $response = array();  
  if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){  
  switch($_GET['apicall']){  
  case 'signup':  
    if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','email','password',))){  
    $username = $_POST['username'];   
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);  
   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM ci_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");  
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);  
    $stmt->execute();  
    $stmt->store_result();  
   
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){  
        $response['error'] = true;  
        $response['message'] = 'User already registered';  
        $stmt->close();  
    }  
    else{  
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ci_users (username, email, password,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");  
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $email, $password);  
   
        if($stmt->execute()){  
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id,id, username, email, FROM users WHERE username = ?");   
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);  
            $stmt->execute();  
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $id, $username, $email);  
            $stmt->fetch();  
   
            $user = array(  
            'id'=>$id,   
            'username'=>$username,   
            'email'=>$email,  
          
            );  
   
            $stmt->close();  
   
            $response['error'] = false;   
            $response['message'] = 'User registered successfully';   
            $response['user'] = $user;   
        }  
    }  
   
}  
else{  
    $response['error'] = true;   
    $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available';   
}  
break;   
case 'login':  
  if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password'))){  
    $username = $_POST['username'];  
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);   
   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, email, mobile_no FROM ci_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");  
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username, $password);  
    $stmt->execute();  
    $stmt->store_result();  
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){  
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $mobile);  
    $stmt->fetch();  
    $user = array(  
    'id'=>$id,   
    'username'=>$username,   
    'email'=>$email,  
    'mobile'=>$mobile  
    );  
   
    $response['error'] = false;   
    $response['message'] = 'Login successfull';   
    $response['user'] = $user;   
 }  
 else{  
    $response['error'] = false;   
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';  
 }  
}  
break;   
default:   
 $response['error'] = true;   
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';  
}  
}  
else{  
 $response['error'] = true;   
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';  
}  
echo json_encode($response);  
function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){  
foreach($params as $param){  
 if(!isset($_POST[$param])){  
     return false;   
  }  
}  
return true;   
}  
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_GET, $_POST)`

Comment: since i am a newbie for php , can you please elaborate what is this and where to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have read your code, it is correct no problem in your code. but the only problem is the postman request data.

According to the method

> isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','email','password',))

you must send these 3 parameters as a request parameter from your postman but according to your attached postman  screen , you have not passed any variables ('username','email','password') and their values under body section.

you have not send any reuest data from postman so according to the definition of this **isTheseParametersAvailable** function, this function return **false** and your code return this message "required parameters are not available"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot and php code you have provided. You may have forgot to send three post parameters namely 'username','email','password' in the body of the request. Which is checked by the function isTheseParametersAvailable in the api endpoint. As given in https://www.javatpoint.com/android-volley-library-registration-login-logout. Your postman request body should look like below.
[image]

Comment: please read the code i attached to my question and tell me where i did mistake. thank you

Comment: problem is not with your code but with your request body parameters..